# Reading text file from a package exported runnable jar file

Tags: java, file-io, executable-jar

I have a package named 'resources' and in it i have a text file named 'score.txt'. I am trying to read and write that file. In eclipse it works but when i exported the project as runnable jar file it cannot find the file.

```
FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        ClassLoader loader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(loader.getResource("resources/score.txt").getFile());
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String s = reader.readLine();
        String[] sep = s.split("-");
        maxScore = Integer.parseInt(sep[0]);
        maxTurn = Integer.parseInt(sep[1]);
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        lblInfo.setText("An error occurred!");
    }
```

Comment: Have you looked in the jar file to see where your `score.txt` file is within it? Why are you calling `getFiles()` rather than just using `getResourceAsStream()`?

Comment: i cannot see the file in it but why ?

Comment: other png files are there but txt file disappears

Comment: Right, so that suggests the problem isn't in your code, but in how you're creating the runnable jar file and/or configuring your build path.

Comment: you mean library handling ?

Comment: Um, not at all sure what you mean by that. But if the resource isn't in the jar file, you're not going to be able to write code to fix that problem - so concentrate on where the problem actually is.

Comment: You can't read the contents of something within a jar file using `java.io.File` and `FileInputStream`s. Those are for on-disk files. Read the URL.

Comment: what should i use?